# Конвертировать double в int

Tags: java, double

Подскажите, как конвертировать `double` в `int`?

Comment: Конвертировать. Уважайте русский язык.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сама конвертация не сложна:

```
double doubleValue = 0.0001;
int value = (int) doubleValue;
```

Т.е. инструкция в общем виде выглядит так:

```
type v1 = (type) v2;
```

Но тут, есть **подводные камни**, а именно - тип `int` содержит значения в диапазоне от `-2147483648` до `2147483647`, притом что они являются целочисленные, т.е. без дробной части. А `double` содержит числа в диапазоне от `4.9E-324` до `4.9E-324`. Т.е. при конвертации может произойти *переполнение* и/или *не учитывание дробной части*.

Для более гибкого преобразования стоит использовать классы `BigDecimal` и `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 7):

Если нужно округлять вверх или вниз, используйте Math.round()

```
double a = 1.8;
int b = Math.round(a); // b = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Double mDouble = 0.25;
int mInt = (int)mDouble;
```

Answer (score 2):

Округляем в нужную сторону.

```
    double dx = 10.787901;
    double newDouble2 = new BigDecimal(dx).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).doubleValue();    

   int ix = (int)newDouble2; // переводим в int
```

`UP` — округление в сторону большего числа для положительных чисел и меньшего для отрицательных.
`DOWN` — округление в сторону меньшего числа для положительных чисел и большего для отрицательных.
`CEILING` — округление в сторону большего и для положительных, и для отрицательных чисел.
`FLOOR` — округление в сторону меньшего и для положительных, и для отрицательных чисел.
`HALF_UP` — округление в большую сторону в случае числа вида 0.5
`HALF_DOWN` — округление в меньшую сторону в случае числа вида 0.5
`HALF_EVEN` — классическое округление

Ссылка на документацию [>>>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)